# Parse request with Express and Multer within controller

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, multer

I have got image uploading working within my project however I would like to organise and tidy it up a bit.

Ideally I want my image uploading to be completed within a function or controller. I have previously had multer completing the image uploading in my route file. Like this:

**route.js:**

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'public/cms/images/uploads')
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, randomString.generate({length: 7, charset: 'alphanumeric'}) + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })
})

router.post('/fileupload', login_controller.requires_login, upload.single('imagefile'), test_controller.file_upload_post);
```

This kind of works. The problem with this, is that I need to setup some restrictions on what can be uploaded and also show error messages back on the template. This would be a lot neater if I had this separated from my routes file.

**Why doesn't this work?**

I am creating a function within a controller called "upload_image" and calling it within the route.

**route.js:**

```
router.post('/blogpost/create', blog_controller.upload_image, blog_controller.blog_create_post);
```

**blogController.js:**

```
exports.upload_image = function (req, res, next) {

    var upload = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, 'public/cms/images/uploads')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, randomString.generate({ length: 7, charset:  'alphanumeric' }) + path.extname(file.originalname))
            }
        })
    })

    upload.single('imagefile');

    return next();

}
```

When I do this the **req.body and req.file** is undefined. No image gets uploaded. There are no error messages and the template renders fine except for anywhere I use req.body or req.file.

Doesn't multer modify the req object with the form data? Doesn't that mean I can then forward it to my other controller after using next(). I want
**blog_controller.blog_create_post** to then do everything else I need with the request.

Thank you, hope you can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `upload.single('imagefile')` does nothing. It's equivalent to doing:

```
exports.upload_image = function (req, res, next) {
    var upload = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, 'public/cms/images/uploads')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, randomString.generate({ length: 7, charset:  'alphanumeric' }) + path.extname(file.originalname))
            }
        })
    })

    function (req, res, next) {}

    return next();

}
```

Remember `multer` is just middleware. The exact logic `multer` takes is shown [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js#L17).

So if I understand the `multer`'s source correctly, something like this may work:

```
exports.upload_image = function (req, res, next) {
    var upload = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, 'public/cms/images/uploads')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, randomString.generate({ length: 7, charset:  'alphanumeric' }) + path.extname(file.originalname))
            }
        })
    })

    returnupload.single('imagefile')(req, res, next)

    return next();

}
```

I have not tested it, but something like that.

Comment: This explains how multer works and I can use this information to make changes. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what (req, res, next) is after the function. Is it short hand for something? I've not used parameters after a function like that.

return upload.single('imagefile')(req, res, next);

Comment: multer returns middleware, that's why you typically use it as `app.post('/', upload.single('file'), ...)` See [using Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).